# Maven - two sources folders with precedence

Tags: java, maven, build-helper-maven-plugin

I have the following situation. I have two different source folders, say `src/main/java` and `src/main/java2`. The two folders are something like two "branches" of the same project. First folder contains all Java files. Second folder contains only a small subset of the same files, in a different version.

I want to create two profiles: first is "normal" profile, where I only build `src/main/java` files; second is the "second branch" profile, where I build all files from both folders, with precedence to second folder: if a file is contained in both folders, the  `src/main/java2` one must be used.

First profile is simple to implement. I cannot create second profile.

I have seen lots of answers using `build-helper-maven-plugin`. However in this case the compile phase gives an error:

```
error: duplicate class
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you should learn to use a version control system like Git or alike (and really use branches)...but not try to do things manually which makes no sense...And profiles is the wrong way....

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Consider extracting an interface, and use an app setting to determine which implementation to use.

Comment: @khmarbaise You are absolutely right. However there are severe constraints in the company envirnoment I am facing.

Comment: You are not allowed to use a version control tool?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes exactly

Comment: That does simply make no sense and prevents usual working etc.